# (principal) sub matrix in the language of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

So we know that every matrix is a linear transformation given some basis. What can we say then about the submatrix (more precisely, principal submatrix) of a given matrix? Is there a nice description of it in terms of linear transformation?

Comment: The term "minor" is usually used to mean the determinant of a submatrix.  Is this what you're talking about, or are you instead interested in the principal submatrix?

Comment: I see. I was talking about submatrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, we have a square matrix $A$ and a corresponding transformation $T:V \to V$. Take $n$ to be the dimension of $V$.

If we have an inner product on the space $V$, then we can say the following. For any choice of rows and columns $1 \leq j_1 < \cdots < j_k \leq n$, the $k \times k$ principal submatrix made of these rows and columns can be expressed as $B^* A B$, where 
$$
B = \pmatrix{e_{j_1} & e_{j_2} & \cdots & e_{j_n}}
$$
and $e_j$ denotes the $j$th canonical basis vector (i.e. the $j$th column of the identity matrix). Note that $B$ is the matrix of an isometry, which is to say that $\|Bx\| = \|x\|$ for all column vectors $x$, or equivalently we have $B^*B = I$.

Correspondingly, for any inner product space and isometry $S: U \to V$, we can consider the linear transformation $T_U = S^* TS$.  $T_U$ is sometimes called a [compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compression_(functional_analysis)) of the transformation $T$ to the space $U$.

Every submatrix of $T$ is the matrix corresponding to a compression of $T$ onto the subspace spanned by $e_{j_1},\dots,e_{j_k}$.  Conversely, every compression of $T$ is the transformation corresponding to a submatrix of $Q^*AQ$ for some unitary matrix $Q$. That is, that compression can be obtained as a submatrix of $A$ after a suitable change of (orthonormal) basis.